# Lenovo Update on ThinkPad x230 w/ SSD confused about AHCI drivers

Tags: windows-7, drivers, thinkpad, ahci

Using Win7 Enterprise 64-bit on a ThinkPad x230 with an SSD.

Lenovo Update 5.06.1006 has me install
Intel Rapid Storage AHCI driver for Windows 64 ver 11.2.0.1006 from Intel dated 5/30/2012

After a reboot, I am prompted to install
Intel Rapid Storage AHCI Driver - 7 (64 bit) ver. 12.8.10.1005 from Intel dated 11/15/2013

which prompts me after a reboot to install the first driver.

Which should stay on the X230?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem. It's not a solution but this thread on Lenovo Support addresses the problem.

[Read Here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/X-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/Lenovo-Update-circling-between-two-different-AHCI-drivers/m-p/1712699)

Comment: Reread that Lenovo post.  Look at the name of the original poster.